# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

10k+ users can probably still see this:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109342/why-were-there-civilians-in-char

[image: Screenshot of the question]

I just clicked on a link to this question, read it, went to upvote but it said the question had been deleted. I (stupidly) refreshed the page, and got the "This question has been deleted" page

I'm not 100% sure why though, it seemed to be a basic game-storyline question (which AFAIK is on-topic).

Would someone be able to tell me what the close reason was, and why this led to the question ultimately getting deleted?

Comment: It was closed as Not Constructive.

Comment: @Robotnik I edited in a screenshot of the currently deleted question.

Comment: Because "Evacuate the civilians" is a randomly selected thing to say, it's not part of the story.  The question is facetious and not useful.

Comment: @MatthewRead - I think a named character saying anything throughout the context of the game is the definition of 'part of the storyline'. Even if the answer was "Most Generals have standard evac procedures drilled into their brains, so barking that order was probably a reflex more than anything" it still would be a valid question. Further, I think the OP was being humorous, not facetious. (The latter is treating serious issues with inappropriate humor). As for 'not useful', could you not argue that about most story & lore questions?

Comment: "Questions about Game Design and Development are off topic. This includes speculative questions about developer intent, as well as lore questions not addressed directly through in-universe sources." We do not handle out of game lore questions.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot In any case it is fairly trivial, I'm not arguing that it should be re-opened, I just wanted to know why it was closed originally. thanks everyone

Comment: @MatthewRead Sounds like a good answer.

Comment: @Robotnik I can't agree that canned lines repeated incessantly suddenly become part of the current story at the moment they are played back.  I have assumed the asker knew it wasn't a valid question, hence the facetiousness.  And to be clear I am stating why it was closed, not making an argument for its closure. We're well past that point.

Comment: @MatthewRead - I assumed it was a trigger-based response (over a canned one), meaning he said it when you storm the main base or something. I wouldn't make the mistake of thinking the asker knew it "wasn't a valid question". He even states *"...just wondering about SC's plot [snip]. I assumed it would be fine, as I've asked other plot questions about Final Fantasy"*. and just so we're clear, an example of facetiousness would be watching someone get electrocuted, and whilst everyone else is calling an ambulance/doing CPR, you say something like "Ho HO! I bet he just got the shock of his life!"

Comment: Anyway as I've stated I think the question itself is trivial, so I'm not arguing for undeletion/reopening here. We're in agreement on that fact

Comment: A better question would be why was the question *undeleted*? It sat closed for 4 months. We delete closed questions (except duplicates). It should've stayed deleted.

Comment: I voted to undelete so I can vote to reopen. I don't see a problem with plot questions that can be answered in game.

Comment: @Resorath Except it's *not* a plot question.  It's random voice work that sometimes gets said.

Comment: @Resorath Except it's been pointed out repeatedly in the comments here that it's not a plot question that is handled in the in-game lore. See comments from MatthewRead and OrigamiRobot.

Comment: @Resorath If it was indeed a random line, and the asker knew that (which I suspect is the case from the way they wrote the question), then it is indeed a question about something not actually in the plot. It would be equivalent to "so I was playing Mario 64 and stopped to look around, when suddenly Mario took off his hat and wiped his head! But I was in the ice level! What's the lore behind why the ice level is sweltering hot?" It's invalid because Mario's hat animation is just a random idle animation unrelated to "lore" or "plot". And the asker knows that, so it's not a serious question.

Comment: @Everyone - I assume noone is bothering to write any of this in the answers section because this decision is (obviously) contentious and not set in stone, but if you guys want to argue for and against can I suggest writing answers here so the community can vote on this accordingly?

Comment: @Robotnik Honestly, it doesn't matter.  The question's been deleted again, and hopefully it stays that way, making it a rather moot point.  Unless someone actually wants to argue it being on-topic.

Comment: @Robotnik Meta votes don't matter. Only close/reopen delete/undelete votes and mod actions do. See the votes on the answers to the meta post, [BioShock Infinite closures on release day](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7053/4797) and compare it with what actually happened to the posts discussed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question was deleted because it was closed, 4 months ago, as Not Constructive. I initiated the push to delete it after a low-rep user had an edit approved on it. We shouldn't be giving people reputation for minor edits to closed questions, particularly ones waiting for deletion.

The fact that this one had been sitting closed, uncontested, for 4 months, was cause enough for me to push for deletion; we delete questions closed as anything but duplicate. It was completely normal.

That being said, it has since been undeleted, re-deleted, and is now on the brink of being undeleted again. Based on [comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/why-was-this-question-deleted#comment21216_7483) seen [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/why-was-this-question-deleted#comment21210_7483), this is a facetious question based on a randomized in-game audio clip, *not* an actual lore question. Thus, it is something we do not handle here. As such, it should remain closed, and deleted.

Comment: Pretty much this. There is no reason for it to stick around.